# WebDriverIO: Firefox does not navigate to url specified

Tags: firefox, webdriver-io

When I run `wdio` with `firefox` as the browser,

- Firefox launches
- it loads the url https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/43.0.3/firstrun/learnmore/
- it does **not** navigate to the `baseUrl` specified in the `wd.conf.js` file
- **neither** does it load any url specified in the spec.
- Firefox just sits there at the *first run* url (screenshot: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img903/3932/7gxuT1.jpg)

Any ideas on how to have Firefox load the specified url's?

---

Chrome works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the correct Selenium Server file.

I have used 2.47.0, 2.48.2, and 2.43.1 and the only one that worked was 2.48.1.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: The webdriver.io [install guide](http://webdriver.io/guide.html) specifies 2.47.0, but only 2.48.1 works for me as well.